# How to remove parentheses from single cref references?

Tags: formatting, cleveref

I am using `cleveref` to cross-reference everything. Sometimes I write the reference inline like `eq.(1)`. That is fine.  But when it is enclosed in parenthesis it turns out like `(eq.(2))`. Which is not so nice.

Is it possible to somehow toggle the use of parenthesis in `cleveref`?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}\label{one}
 12+2=34
 \end{equation}
 \begin{equation}\label{two}
 1+2=4
 \end{equation}
 if \cref{one} is correct than (\cref{two})!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add an example document showing exactly how are you obtaining those references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a “variable” format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{\eqA eq.~\eqB #2#1#3)}
\newcommand{\eqA}{}
\newcommand{\eqB}{(}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pcref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\eqA}{(}\renewcommand{\eqB}{}%
  \cref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2 \label{true}
\end{equation}

Here's \cref{true}.

That's all \pcref{true}.

Again \cref{true}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou. Now I just have to go do this for all of my section, chapter, table, figure references as well :P

Comment: Is it possible to make this take an optional argument, if I would like to add something like `(figure 13a)`? I mean adding the a manually without using subcaptions, if the letter is hardcoded in the figure. My TeX skills are unfortunately not up to par here

Comment: @niclasericsson Sorry, but this site doesn't work like this. Please, open a new question and specify what precisely you'd like to get.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified version of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263532/133968). This works for multiple references and also for all kinds of references.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newcommand{\eqlabelleft}{(}
\newcommand{\eqlabelright}{)}
\newcommand{\pcref}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\eqlabelleft}{}%
\renewcommand{\eqlabelright}{}%
(\cref{#1})%
\endgroup%
}

\creflabelformat{equation}{\eqlabelleft#2#1#3\eqlabelright}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    y = mx + c
    \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2 = 1
    \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
\cref{eq:1,eq:2}\\
\pcref{eq:1,eq:2}\\
\cref{eq:1,eq:2}
\end{document}
```

[image]