# How can I get cleveref to surround references with parentheses automatically?

Tags: cleveref, parentheses

I use `cleveref` for in-document references, and find it to be clever. However, I typically want to refer to figures (for example) within parentheses. What I do now is this

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
...
X exhibits Y (\cref{fig:foo}).
```

but what I would like to do is something like

```
X exhibits Y \cref{fig:foo}. % Parentheses omitted in code but not in output
```

Ideally I would have some way to omit parentheses in output when needed.

Comment: A quick (not good) solution: Redefining `\cref` on itself.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: @JouleV Nice suggestion. It looks to me like this is the cleanest solution, as I reason in my comment to @cmhughes' answer. It also leaves the original `\cref` for parenthesis-less refs. Is there any good reason against?

Comment: @AugustJanse If you want, this is the solution: `\makeatletter \let\my@command\cref \renewcommand\cref[1]{[\my@command{#1}]} \makeatother`

Comment: Reverse question on how to **remove** the parenthesis (which is there by default in equation/subequations etc.): [hyperref - Omit round brackets around equation numbers with cleveref - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373063/omit-round-brackets-around-equation-numbers-with-cleveref). See also [formatting - Is it possible to remove parenthesis from single cref references? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263523/is-it-possible-to-remove-parenthesis-from-single-cref-references) for alternative solutions that allow toggling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not modify the workings of `\cref` and friends directly. Instead, I would create a new macro called `\pcref` -- short for "parenthetic \cref", I suppose -- as follows:

```
\newcommand\pcref[1]{(\cref{#1})}
```

As you can probably guess, `\pcref` places round parentheses around the output of `\cref`. No need for lots of separate `\crefformat` directives. This approach preserves access to the standard definition of `\cref`, should the need to do so arise.

For the following screenshot, I loaded the `hyperref` package and specified the `cleveref` option `nameinlink`, in order to make visible what is, and is not, produced by `\cref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newcommand\pcref[1]{(\cref{#1})}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!] \caption{foo}\label{fig:foo}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!] \caption{bar}\label{fig:bar}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!] \caption{foo}\label{tab:foo}\end{table}

\dots\ \pcref{fig:foo}, \pcref{fig:foo,fig:bar}, \pcref{tab:foo,fig:bar}, \dots

\bigskip vs.

\bigskip
\dots\ \cref{fig:foo}, \cref{fig:foo,fig:bar}, \cref{tab:foo,fig:bar}, \dots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Referencing Section 8.2.1 of the `cleveref` documention,

> Cross-reference formats for single cross-references are defined or
>   redefined using the `\crefformat` and `\Crefformat` commands, which are
>   used by the `\cref` and `\Cref` commands respectively. These take two
>   arguments: the cross-reference type, and the formatting code:
>   `\crefformat{type}{format}`

For your purposes, we can use, for example:

```
\crefformat{figure}{(Figure~#2#1#3)}
\Crefformat{figure}{Figure~#2#1#3}
```

Note that I've used `crefformat` for use with the `\cref` command (not beginning of sentence), and `Crefformat` for use with the `Cref` command (beginning of sentence).

This gives

[image]

A complete MWE follows

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{figure}{(Figure~#2#1#3)}
\Crefformat{figure}{Figure~#2#1#3}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \rule{3mm}{2mm}
    \caption{August}
    \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

X exhibits Y \cref{fig:foo}.

\Cref{fig:foo} is a cross reference at the beginning of a sentence
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This certainly is a solution, but it's a bit unwieldy. I would need to `\crefformat` every type of object (tables for example) and rewrite a few sentences to have the ref at the beginning, or alternatively reset the format before and after.

I was hopeful for `\crefdefaultlabelformat`, but it looks like that only affects the label and not the name. Reading the part of the documentation you referred to, it looks like there's no better solution using `cleveref`.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to Mico's idea, the same can be done for \crefrange :

\newcommand\pcrefrange[2]{(\crefrange{#1}{#2})}

However, it is problematic if we want the (1)--(2) notation instead of (1--2), the former being much more widespread.

See those posts :

[Obtain (1)‒(3) style when referring to ranges of examples, when default \crefrangelabelformat has no parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637155/obtain-1-3-style-when-referring-to-ranges-of-examples-when-default-crefran)

[Local cross-referencing with Linguex/Philex and Cleveref: Skipping 1st and 2nd level sublabels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634519/local-cross-referencing-with-linguex-philex-and-cleveref-skipping-1st-and-2nd-l/637115#637115)