# Skipping non-numeric part of counter label in local Cross-referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, linguex

When quoting linguistic examples from authors inside a quotation, I like to use a special label specifying the name of the author. (I enclose it between square brackets but it will not appear here because irrelevant.)

When referring to multiple examples and subexamples **by the same author** I want to be able to skip this special non-numeric label and only keep the number.

\StrCut from `xstring` works nicely to strip at the non-breakable space which stands between the Author Name and the number.

However, when there is no delimiter, the usual solution with `cleveref`, \crefstripprefix, does not work as intended, see MWE.

Besides, stripping to the level2/level3 delimiter with \StrCut to obtain *Author 1a.i--iii* works, but yields a critical error if `hyperref` is loaded.

Let me point out that I do not specifically need ranges, which are already working using an alternative "tweaking" approach as shown in the mwe.

I just want to be able to skip the Author Name when referring to the example, it would allow the required flexibility for multiple refs which are not ranges, such as "Author 1a.ii, 2b.i".

All credits for the coding can be found here :
[Cross-referencing: more sublevels, and presets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637164/cross-referencing-more-sublevels-and-presets)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{philex} % Linguex wrapper. Awesome despite the "non-academic" coding.
\usepackage{xstring} % Provides the \StrCut command.
\usepackage{refcount} % Provides the \getrefbykeydefault command.
\usepackage{cleveref} % For ranges.


\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\crefname{bpa}{}{} % Main Counter
\crefname{SubExNo}{}{} % Sublevel.
\crefname{SubSubExNo}{}{}

\newcommand{\dotstrip}[2]{\StrCut{#1}{.}{\onea}{\oneb}%
    \StrCut{#2}{.}{\twoa}{\twob}%
    \IfStrEq{\onea}{\twoa}{\twob}{#2}}

\newcommand{\spacestrip}[2]{\StrCut{#1}{~}{\onea}{\oneb}%
\StrCut{#2}{~}{\twoa}{\twob}%
\IfStrEq{\onea}{\twoa}{\twob}{#2}}

\crefrangelabelformat{bpa}{(#3#1#4--#5\spacestrip{#1}{#2}#6)} %   Stripping to the non-brakable space, so that Author is not repeated.
\crefrangelabelformat{SubExNo}{(#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6)} % Usually outputs 1a--b but does not work here.
\crefrangelabelformat{SubSubExNo}{(#3#1#4--#5\dotstrip{#1}{#2}#6)} % Used with roman numbering, which confuses crefstripprefix. But you need a separator (a dot in this variant).




\begin{document}

    % Philex Formatting
    
    \phildashes{}{.}        % Adds a dot between levels 2 and 3 in references.
    \subformat{a}{}{.}      % Level 2 is of the form “a.”
    \subsubformat{i}{(}{)}  % Level 3 is of the form “(i)”



\bpaformat{1}{Author~}{}

\lbpa{main1}{Example One.
    \lba{sub11}{Subexample One-One.
        \lba{subsub111}{Subsubexample One-One-One.}
        \lbb{subsub112}{Subsubexample One-One-Two.}
        \lbz{subsub113}{Subsubexample One-One-Three}}
    \lbz{sub12}{Subexample One-Two.
        \lba{subsub121}{Subsubexample One-Two-One.}
        \lbz{subsub122}{Subsubexample One-Two-Two.}}}

\lbpa{main2}{Example Two.}


When quoting different examples, I do not want \textit{Author} to be repeated.

Works very nicely with xstring's StrCut for the 1st level...

\crefrange{main1}{main2}

... but the 3rd does not work if hypperref is loaded :

\textbackslash crefrange\{subsub111\}\{subsub113\} yields a critical error.

\vspace{6pt}
... and more importantly, level 2 does not work at all because \textbackslash crefstripprefix fails:

\textbackslash crefrange\{sub11\}\{sub12\}  should output “Author 1a--b” but instead I get the following error :

“Improper alphabetic constant.”

\vspace{12pt}

Of course an alternative approach is to refer to “parts” so we can “cheat” and build the refs manually:
Philex already has \textbackslash rfx/rnx command to skip the main level.

Then we may define a new command to skip the first sublevel :



\makeatletter

    \@ifdefinable\gobbletodot{\long\def\gobbletodot#1.{}}% refcount package
    \newcommand\delbefdot[1]{%
      \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\gobbletodot#1.}$%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
      {#1}{\expandafter\delbefdot\expandafter{\gobbletodot#1}}%
    }%
    \@ifdefinable\rfxx{%
      \DeclareRobustCommand\rfxx[1]{%
        \IfRefUndefinedBabel{#1}{\refused{#1}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}%
                            {%
                              \@ifundefined{hyperref}{\@firstofone}{\hyperref[{#1}]}%
                              {%
                                (\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\delbefdot
                                \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{??}})%
                              }%
                            }%
      }%
    }%
    \@ifdefinable\rnxx{%
      \DeclareRobustCommand\rnxx[1]{%
        \IfRefUndefinedBabel{#1}{\refused{#1}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}%
                            {%
                              \@ifundefined{hyperref}{\@firstofone}{\hyperref[{#1}]}%
                              {%
                                \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\delbefdot
                                \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{??}}%
                              }%
                            }%
      }%
    }%

\makeatother



\newcommand{\rfstrip}[2]{(\rn{#1}--\rnx{#2})}
\newcommand{\rfdoublestrip}[2]{(\rn{#1}--\rnxx{#2})}

\rfstrip{sub11}{sub12}
\rfdoublestrip{subsub111}{subsub113}

\vspace{6pt}

But we lose systematicity and besides, “Author 1a.i, 2b.”  is also something I would like.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer's examplification [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644002/262813) on how to use the brilliant package `zref`, I put forward a quick illustration of how to solve the problem raised by myself in the original post.

All is much easier after that, as you will see.

(Of course \zlabel will have to replace \label everywhere in any linguistic package which includes the latter, so that we do not have to add it manually, but this is trivial.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\usepackage{philex}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{exno}{\arabic{ExNo}}
\zref@newprop{subexno}{\alph{SubExNo}}
\zref@newprop{subsubexno}{\roman{SubSubExNo}}

\zref@newprop{authorstrip}{\bota{bpa}\alph{SubExNo}{\ifnum\theExDepth=3\roman{SubSubExNo}\fi}} % Here is the key line.

\zref@newprop{refstrip}{\ifnum\theExDepth=3\roman{SubSubExNo}\else\alph{SubExNo}\fi}

\zref@addprops{main}{exno,subexno,subsubexno,authorstrip,refstrip}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\authorstrip}[2]{(\zref{#1},\,\zref[authorstrip]{#2})}

\newcommand{\rfxx}[1]{(\zref[subsubexno]{#1})}

\newcommand{\rfstrip}[2]{(\zref{#1}--\zref[refstrip]{#2})}

\begin{document}

\phildashes{}{.} 
\subformat{a}{}{.}     

\bpaformat{1}{Author~}{}

\lbpa{main1}{Example One.\zlabel{mainex}
    \lba{sub11}{Subexample One-One.\zlabel{sub11}
        \lba{subsub111}{Subsubexample One-One-One.}\zlabel{subsub111}
        \lbb{subsub112}{Subsubexample One-One-Two.}
        \lbz{subsub113}{Subsubexample One-One-Three.\zlabel{subsub113}}} 
    \lbz{sub12}{Subexample One-Two.\zlabel{sub12}
        \lba{subsub121}{Subsubexample One-Two-One.}
        \lbz{subsub122}{Subsubexample One-Two-Two.}}}

\lbpa{main2}{Example Two.
        \lba{sub21}{Subexample Two-One.}
        \lbz{sub22}{Subexample Two-Two.}} \zlabel{sub22}
        
\vspace{6pt}

Results :

\rfxx{subsub113}

\rfstrip{subsub111}{subsub113}

\rfstrip{sub11}{sub12}

\authorstrip{subsub111}{sub22}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit:

To extract the Author Name variable alone, which corresponds to Argument 3 of the command `\bpaformat`, just add inside the definition of the latter the following command:

```
\gdef\theauthor{#3}
```

The command `\gdef` is a very effective way to extract any argument from any command. Just be sure to use it inside the definition, so that the variable can be accessible, by means of the argument-referencing code #*n* (where *n* is the argument rank, counting from left to right).

Comment: Every pro of cross-ref is named Ulrike :) Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Don't mix up the two names: 1. Ulrike Fischer 2. Ulrich Diez. ;-)

Comment: Ulrike is a female name.  Ulrich is a male name.

Comment: Wow, we learn everyday! That makes sense, morphologically speaking. ;) Thanks Ulrike! And Ulrich... Both of you ahah.

Comment: English is not my first language. ;-)

Comment: Neither is it mine. I'm French.

Comment: So both of us are from earth. ;-)