# Refer to a specific token of a cross-ref label / Clarifications on refcount and zref

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, linguex

First, before any downvoting, I am aware of the existence and content of this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577464/262813 and let me point out that I am not asking this question out of nowhere, without having thought it through many times and having spent time on writing complete questions and answers.

I am a beginner and I really do not understand something, i.e. how to refer to one specific token of a reference having only one global label at your disposal.

Let's say you set a subexample which is numbered 2b.i, and you label it *label-of-2bi*; now  if want my ref to print in the shape of *i*, skipping both first and second tokens, well, I'm sure it's quite simple, but I still do not get it.

All I understand is that the print string I seek is \theSubSubExNo or \theSubExNo, but those commands do not take arguments, they print the current value of the corresponding counter (\SubSubExNo and \SubExNo).
What I need is to be able to **refer to what their value was at a specific point**. But I don't know how to assign labels to them. And package `zref` is far beyond my level of comprehension.

I believe I am seeing a solution, based on several answers and comments by @Ulrich Diez's so valuable help; it involves \getrefbykeydefault from package `refcount`.

I have read the documentation of the package about that valuable command, I know it takes 3 arguments, i.e. **label, key, default**, but I do not know what values I should assign to variables 2 and 3 (for example, in Ulrich's \KeepOnlyStuffBehindLastDot proposal, I can see that the third is a double question mark, I have absolutely no idea what this means).

I use `linguex` or `linguex`-based packages.

My previous interrogations :

- [Understanding some aspects of the philex package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/638170/262813)
- [Cross-referencing: more sublevels, and presets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637164/262813)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637115/262813
- [Skipping non-numeric part of counter label in local Cross-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643154/262813)

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{linguex}
 \begin{document}
    \ex. \label{lakintpur}
    \a. \label{lakintpura}\a. Greg's intention was to overthrow the
    government. \label{intention}
    \b. Greg's purpose was to overthrow the government. \label{purpose}
    \z.\b.\label{lakintpurb}\a. Greg intended to overthrow the
    government. \label{intendv}
    \b.*Greg purposed to overthrow the government. \label{purposev}
    
     \textbackslash ref\{intention\} prints as \ref{intention} but I would like to print only (i) (if being discussing (1-a) extensively),
     \vspace{1em}
     
      or (as \textbackslash rfx from the package philex achieves) print (a.i) if being discussing (1) globally.
      
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `\getrefbykeydefault` the default denotes the tokens to deliver in case referencing does not work out. E.g., because the corresponding referencing-label is not defined. So with `??` as default you get two question-marks in the text when using `\getrefbykeydefault` for attempting to reference a label where no corresponding `\label`-command is in the source code of your document.

Comment: With `\getrefbykeydefault` the key denotes which piece of data associated to the referencing-label you which to obtain. That could be the textual phrase denoting the page-number which you get via `\pageref`. That could be the textual phrase of what you get via `\ref`. That could be the name of the destination for the hyperlink which `\ref`/`\pageref` creates besides delivering textual phrase.

Comment: I could not understand, when reading the documentation, what "key" I should use for the sublevel or subsublevel.

Comment: Cross-references don't have such things as level/sublevel/subsublevel. In my answer to [How to prevent reference to enumeration inside new environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/118714) I tried to give an outline of how cross-referencing is implemented in LaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the aux-file you can see that the label is stored like this:

```
\newlabel{intention}{{\hbox {(1-a-i)}}{1}}
```

While it is not impossible to extract the `i` from this,  is not trivial how to do it and refcount can't help with it.

If you really want access to sub counters, you should use a more powerful reference system like `zref` that allows you to store and retrieve more values independently

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{exno}{\arabic{ExNo}}
\zref@newprop{subexno}{\alph{SubExNo}}
\zref@newprop{subsubexno}{(\roman{SubSubExNo})}

\zref@addprops{main}{exno,subexno,subsubexno}

\makeatother
 \begin{document}
    \ex. \zlabel{lakintpur}
    \a. \zlabel{lakintpura}\a. Greg's intention was to overthrow the
    government. \zlabel{intention} 
    \b. Greg's purpose was to overthrow the government. \zlabel{purpose}
    \z.\b.\zlabel{lakintpurb}\a. Greg intended to overthrow the
    government. \zlabel{intendv}
    \b.*Greg purposed to overthrow the government. \zlabel{purposev}

     \textbackslash ref\{intention\} prints as \zref[subsubexno]{intention} but I would like to print only (i) 
     
     Test: \zref{intention}, \zref[exno]{intention}, \zref[subexno]{intention}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I can define whatever formats I want, such as \zref[exno]{#1}.\zref[subexno]{#1}. 
Is it possible to factorize?

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean by factorize. You can define more properties, e.g. exno+subexno, you can also extract the values and make comparisions.

Comment: Sorry I meant put the #1 only once in common factor such as {\zref[exno].\zref[subexno]}{#1}. I guess this is basic LaTeX syntax but it just came to my mind. I guess I just have to define a combined property exno+subexno as you suggest.

Comment: No that won't work. But in a definition it shouldn't matter much that you have to repeat the `#1`. But as I said you can also define a new property `\zref@newprop{exno+subexno}{\arabic{ExNo}.\alph{SubExNo}}` and then use `\zref[exno+subexno]{label}`.

Comment: This package really makes referencing pleasant and flexible. I thought it was much more complicated but I got the basics, I think.

Comment: yes, zref is much easier to adapt then cleveref. You could also check https://ctan.org/pkg/zref-clever

Comment: What, a combination of zref and cref? I have a feeling I will like this one. ;)
Sounds perfect, thanks...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136276/discussion-between-vincent-krebs-and-ulrike-fischer).