# Remove parentheses for only one reference

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem, cleveref

I need to reference some items from an `enumerate` environment. I can do this by adding a label at the beginning of each `\item` (see MWE at the bottom). So far, so good.

Each item in the enumerate has a parenthesis (set through the `(\arabic*)` option) and I would like to keep it that way. However, this creates an issue when referencing the label: if I do so within a parenthetical in my text, I will have two consecutive opening or closing parentheses (see image at the end of the result). I find this undesirable.

Is there a way I can change this default behavior, but only for *some* cross-references? To be clear, I would prefer to keep the same format of the `enumerate` list (numbers within parentheses) and the format of the "normal" cross-reference (outside of a parenthetical); only a couple cross-references would have to be edited manually. In other words, I do not want to change the default reference behavior across the whole document. The desired result, in the example image below, would be:

> I reference items: (1). But what if I use parentheses (for example, 2)?

(note the lack of double parentheses).

Is there a way to achieve this? I suppose I need to use the `enumitem` and `cleveref` packages (which I have loaded anyway), but I am open to all suggestions.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
    This is a list:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
        \item\label{item:apple} Apple
        \item\label{item:pear} Pear
        \item\label{item:orange} Orange
    \end{enumerate}
    I reference items: \ref{item:apple}. But what if I use parentheses (for example, \ref{item:pear})?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should seriously consider adding the option `ref=\arabic*` to the list of options with which you initiate the `enumerate` environment. This will remove *all* parentheses from the cross-referencing call-outs to enumerated items. In my opinion, it's highly desirable to remove the parentheses from *all* cross-referencing call-outs, and not just from those call-outs that happen to be located inside parenthetic expressions.

Comment: See also [formatting - Is it possible to remove parenthesis from single cref references? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263523/is-it-possible-to-remove-parenthesis-from-single-cref-references)